# Prometheus init.d start with additional arguments

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I need help. How me to run prometheus with additional arguments, i have OS Debian 8, i run example:

**/etc/init.d/promethus start**  -  ok
**/etc/init.d/promethus ---storage.local.memory-chunks=336342 start** - doesn't work.

I dont know another variant's  solutions this  trouble.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/init.d/promethus` is a service init script rather than Prometheus binary executable, typically you'll use it like:

- sudo service prometheus start/stop/status/restart

To pass additional arguments to the daemon you're going to start, you can configure arguments in file `/etc/default/prometheus`, or you can read the shell script to see if there's any environment variable could be used.

Comment: Thank you for the solution of my problem

Comment: @Djam36, glad to help :-)

Comment: I was looking for a good way to add `alertmanager.url` and this was the answer. Hopefully now this will show up in google for others.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian-based systems, you can usually add arguments in the file for the service under `/etc/default`

Comment: Thank you for the solution of my problem